# refinery cms-blog showing error while migrating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, refinerycms

i want to integrate a blog with my existing rails app,
i used gem refinerycms-blog and followed the tutorial  https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-blog

while migrating i get this error

```
uninitialized constant Refinery::Blog::Post::FriendlyId/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/refinerycms-blog-2.0.5/app/models/refinery/blog/post.rb:7:in `<class:Post>'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/refinerycms-blog-2.0.5/app/models/refinery/blog/post.rb:6:in `<module:Blog>'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/refinerycms-blog-2.0.5/app/models/refinery/blog/post.rb:5:in `<module:Refinery>'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/refinerycms-blog-2.0.5/app/models/refinery/blog/post.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/love/rails/nabthat/db/migrate/20130813172727_create_blog_structure.refinery_blog.rb:5:in `up'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:119:in `with_connection'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/home/love/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:153:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

How can i solve this or is there any better blog available

Answer (score 0):

I found a link in the github that matches your problem, https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-blog/issues/296 . As described, they have fixed the problem.

It seems like your refinerycms-blog's version is too low, try `gem 'refinerycms-blog', '~> 2.1.0'` or `gem 'refinerycms-blog', :git => 'https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-blog.git'` for latest version.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For rails 4.1.5, Open up your Gemfile and add:

```
gem 'refinerycms-blog', git: 'https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-blog', branch: 'master'
```

Note: if the refinerycms-page-images extension is also installed, make sure gem refinerycms-blog comes before gem 'refinerycms-page-images'.